# spamProtectEmailAddresses Typo3 deactivate only in one specific page

Tags: typo3, typoscript, spam-prevention, typo3-4.5

I am managing an association's site using typo3 version 4.5.30. The site has the config setup for spam protection

```
[spamProtectEmailAddresses] = -3 
# config.absRefPrefix = http://www.afj-japon.org/ # Protection contre le spam
[spamProtectEmailAddresses_atSubst] = /-/arobase-//
[spamProtectEmailAddresses_lastDotSubst] = [dot]
```

Every time content is created that includes an email address, it encrypts it fine. 
I need to have this functionality disabled for one page only. How should I set it up ?

Answer (score 5):

You can create an extension template at that specific site and just override the TypoScript definition there.

Or you use a condition on your global template that checks for the given UID of the page and reset the spam protection inside the condition block.

Answer (score 0):

To Add Span Protection in typo3 project add this lines into template > setup.

config {

// Protect mail addresses from spamming
  spamProtectEmailAddresses = -3
  spamProtectEmailAddresses_atSubst = @remove-this.

}

I hope this help !!!